# Hibernate native query is throwing exception for "ORDER BY FIELD()"

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project *(version: 2.0.0.M1)* where I am using MySQL DB.

My user repository extends `JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer>`. Following method is throwing exception after upgrading my spring boot version to 2.x.x.RELEASE:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from user as u where u.is_deleted = FALSE order by field (u.id, :idList)",
nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> findNonDeletedOrderByIdList(@Param("idList") List<Integer> idList, Pageable pageable);
```

Exception is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve given parameter name [idList] to QueryParameter reference

Please help me.

**Note:** It may duplicate with [Hibernate criteria for sql ORDER BY FIELD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290712/hibernate-criteria-for-sql-order-by-field)

### UPDATE:

I don't know why, after inserting `AND u.id IN (:idList)` before `order by` it is working

```
@Query(value = "Select * from user as u where u.is_deleted = FALSE AND u.id IN (:idList) order by field (u.id, :idList)", nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> findNonDeletedOrderByIdList(@Param("idList") List<Integer> idList, Pageable pageable);
```

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: You cannot use parameters in an order by clause, only the where clause.

Comment: I have mentioned, this code was working fine on previous boot version. Now it's working fine after inserting 'IN' operator. @M.Deinum

Comment: Because IN is part of the where clause NOT the order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, after inserting `AND u.id IN (:idList)` before `order by` it is working

```
@Query(value = "Select * from user as u where u.is_deleted = FALSE AND u.id IN (:idList) order by field (u.id, :idList)", nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> findNonDeletedOrderByIdList(@Param("idList") List<Integer> idList, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem, I think your SQL is not valid.

Order by cannot have a parameter

Try just this:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from user as u where u.is_deleted = FALSE order by u.id ASC, nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> findNonDeletedOrderByIdList(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: SQL is valid for MySQL 5.6. I have mentioned, this code was working fine on previous boot version.